# Xcode: "Find In Project" doesn't find some text

Tags: xcode, find, full-text-search, project

In Xcode 5.1.1 'Find In Project' seems to be behaving erratically. Sometimes it doesn't find targets.  I double checked in the Find Navigator: scope of search is "In Project" and the search modifier "Ignoring Case" is selected.  Some target text is found successfully, and other target text is not found - even when it occurs within THE SAME SOURCE FILEs.

For example I can Find In Project "theHousehold" (a property name), with multiple source files and occurrences located.  But if I search for "NSAssert", Find In Project returns 'No Results Found for "NSAssert"' - even though a local file Find of the same text is successful.

Here's a clue or perhaps a red herring - sometimes when searching with the Standard Editor's Find, the count of occurrences goes to zero - even for text that it successfully finds. Does Xcode build a full text search index, and can I trigger a rebuild of it?

I am pretty sure this has worked in the past.  I have already tried "Clean Build Folder" and restarted Xcode.  I don't see any prefs or settings that I might have munged - I'm stumped.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One extra setting to check: in the Find Navigator there is a hierarchical control (just above the search target box) for "Find/Replace", then additional   for "Text/References/Definitions/Regular Expression" then "Containing/Matching/Starting with/Ending With".  I had inadvertently switched from "Text" to "References".  Only certain constructs were recognized, others weren't.  Surprise, xCode was behaving correctly, just not as I expected.

Lastly, the way to force a text index rebuild is from the Organizer Window.  Select the project, then press the Delete button for the "Derived Data".  This forces a rebuild.

(For recent versions of Xcode, link to this question: [How to delete derived data in Xcode 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38016143/1035697))

All is working now!

Comment: WTF, who changed it? not me for sure (!) Thanks, this turned my Xcode again into a proper developing tool.